# Slack native application only shows an icon in plank but no window

Tags: release-freya, applications

I have tried and tried installing/removing Slack native App.

It installs correctly but when I start it, I only see the icon on the Plank dock but no window.

I know about ScudCloud (stopped due to performance issues) and currently am running Slack as Chrome ( App mode ) but I would rather want to run the default app that gives me native notifications.

Can anybody please help with running the native App ?

Comment: I had this but I don't remember the lib it's missing, if you run it through terminal, I believe it mentions a libs it's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, today I downloaded a fresh app  ( .deb [64bit] ) from Slack site and surprisingly it worked.

Either some downstream fixes from Elementary packages or fixed version 2.0.6 of Slack application, but the app works now.